# CSS :hover - How to get lower DIVs to :hover as well?

Tags: jquery, css

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/aPUT6/) is an example. I'm looking to get the row and the column the cursor is over to display the :hover attributes. Is there a way to do this without requiring javascript? If not is there a simple way in jQuery to do this for any number of rows/cols?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not with css, as with css only one element is hovered (*from overlapping non-nested elements*).

jQuery can help but it is not trivial..

A crude implementation would be to

- add `.row` and `.col` classes to the elements (*as appropriate*)
- bind a custom event to those, whose handler check to see if the mouse coords are inside their box and set/unset the hover state
- while the mouse moves inside the container of the rows and cols (*you should wrap them in one*), create an event (*of the custom type we bound to the rows and cols*) and fire it globally

**html**

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="row1" class="row"></div>
    <div id="row2" class="row"></div>
    <div id="col1" class="col"></div>
    <div id="col2" class="col"></div>
</div>
```

**javascript**

```
$('.col, .row').bind('intersect',function(e){
    var $me = $(this);
    var pos = $me.offset();
    var size = {w:$me.width(), h:$me.height()};

    if ( e.pageX > pos.left && e.pageY > pos.top && e.pageX < pos.left + size.w && e.pageY < pos.top + size.h )
    {
        $me.addClass('hover');
    }
    else if ($me.is('.hover'))
    {
        $me.removeClass('hover');
    }
});

$('#container').mousemove(function(e){
    var evt = jQuery.Event('intersect');
    evt.pageX = e.pageX;
    evt.pageY = e.pageY;
    $.event.trigger(evt);
});
```

**demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/7V8AN/

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a table, you can normally just do something like this:

```
tr:hover > td {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

…but if you have elements that aren't nested, only one of them will be considered `:hover`ed. You'd have to use JavaScript to propagate the hover state to other elements that are positioned underneath.

Comment: Can be anything, not just a table.

Answer (score 0):

I would use jquery siblings:

```
$("#row1").siblings("#row2").css(attr, value);
```

or you could use .class or anything like that.